# Error in configurating chat

Tags: community, chat

I try to configure chat in a developer org and i put all the info but in the end i get this message. Any ideas? I post the process i follow and in the last pic is the problem.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the configuration as well

Comment: sure i am going to update the question as soon as possible

Comment: If you exit out and retry from new, does it work?

Comment: also double check the community URL